# topology- evaluation functions into products

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a Tychonoff space, prove that the family of all continuous real-valued functions on $X$ distinguishes points

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts that you can share so responders can have some ideas of how to respond? Regards

Answer (score 2):

Consider the definitions of a completely regular space and of a family of functions separating points.